# How to list ALL indices using elasticsearch.js client

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch.js

I need to list all indices in my node.js app, using elasticsearch.js node module.
What I have is:

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: 'localhost:9200',
  log: 'trace'
});

  client.indices.get({

  })
```

The error I get is:

```
(node:72002) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Unable to build a path with those params. Supply at least index
```

What is the proper syntax for client.indices.get, which would list all available indices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
const indices = await client.cat.indices({format: 'json'})
console.log('indices:', indices)
```

or else

```
client.cat.indices("b",function(r,q){
  console.log(r,q);
}) }]);
```

Hope it helps.